# How to observe / trace class member access in Java / Scala?

Tags: java, scala, attributes, listener, trace

I'm developing a Scala extension to an existing Java ORM (Ebean). The goal of this project is to add as much type safety as possible to the ORM.
Instead of

```
Ebean.find(Product.class).fetch("name", "unit").findList()
```

I would finally like to be able to write something like

```
(objects of entity[Product] with attributes name and unit) getIt
```

(note that this is just a very first DSL approach).

The ORM model is already defined as

```
@Entity
public class {
    public String name;
    public String unit;
}
```

**In order to achieve type safety at compile time for the attributes in the query, I would need to access them on e.g. a dummy object like `(new Product()).name`.**

I think this is the best way to ensure that only such model members are used that exists on that class, but, at runtime, I need a way to recognize that this variable was accessed. Otherwise I would just call that member `name` and wouldn't know about this in my query.

Does anybody know a way how to achieve this? **Is there a possibility to trace when a variable is accessed and to give that information, at runtime, to any other object?**

I already thought about hooking into getters and setters instead of using public members in the model classes, but this would either make the query or the model very ugly. Another problem is that any additional specific methods would have to be added manually for each model.

I would be happy if anyone could suggest possible solutions. Thanks!

Comment: I am actually quite fond of the "automated type building" approach as found in LINQ2SQL or other template DALs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to define the fields of your model objects as something like the Record Fields, what Emil suggested could work, but if you're building your solution on top of a Java ORM using custom types might be an issue.  If you need to track field access I think your best bet will be runtime bytecode instrumentation using a library like [CGLib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) or [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).  You can pass an instrumented "dummy" object into the body of your function, then track which field was accessed in a thread local.  That's how it's done in [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org).

Comment: Thanks for the inspiring answer! I decided to probably use bytecode manipulation through Javassist. Since I want to build on top of an existing Java ORM, I cannot use custom types in my model. Some prototyping showed that it could be a well-suited solution to change attribute accesses into calls of coexisting wrappers. Of course, the scope of this manipulation must be limited but I think it is an appropriate solution to e.g. annotate the usages of typesafe select queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a gander at how the Lift folks have implemented [Mapper](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapper) and Records. It allows for type safe queries using companion objects (as well as using raw sql). It does require inheriting traits into your model and the fields are specified as objects and not regular vals. Might be helpfull though. You can find the source for the persistance stuff [here](https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/persistence).